I'm creating a bot auto replier for my personal subreddit
I'm creating a bot auto replier for my personal subreddit. This will comment on every post started in the subreddit, and paste the rules, and other info. However, when I test this out my accounts are getting shadow banned. I made the mistake of testing it with my personal account, and I've also created a couple of new accounts and all of them have been affected. I am using python and PRAW, the python reddit api wrapper in order to access the reddit api.
I've tried with multiple accounts and all are getting shadow banned. This only happens when I use the bot and if I comment manually there are no issues.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
